# Dockerfile for elasticsearch not running

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is the directory structure

es/
---/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
---docker-compose.yml

here is the dockerfile context

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN echo "hello World"
RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    build: ./elasticsearch/    
    container_name: es01
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1      
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      #- discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      #- cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
        hki_default:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.0.120           
networks:
  hki_default:
     external: true
```

After run docker-compose up , i go into the container command line to 
`bin/elasticsearch-plugin list` 
the plugin is still not installed

had tried

```
build: ./elasticsearch
build: elasticsearch/
build: ./elasticsearch/Dockerfile
```

but none of about work
Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have console output? How do we know there wasn't an error during the install?

Comment: no errors..........